# What is this funny noise coming from my car only when I reverse?

Tags: transmission, noise, opel, agila

My 2003 Opel Agila is making a really funny grinding/squealing noise coming from the front of the car only when I reverse, also when I go forwards sometimes you can hear it but it's really quiet, it's so loud when you reverse.

I made a recording of it on [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/george109/reversing-noise/s-KMely)

Is it the gearbox?

Comment: The recording quality isn't that great, so for clarification: do you mean the whining sound that every manual transmission car makes in reverse, or the very high-pitched squealing sound?

Comment: I have your same car and that noise doesn't sound normal to me at all (it only makes the typical reversing noise any car makes, and only when the car is actually moving in reverse, but not the squealing). Never heard it on mine. Sounds like a gearbox issue to me (the gearbox is in the front of the car, actually). Does it make it even when completely stationary? If you can, check if the manual trans oil has been replaced at the required mileage (30000 kms).

Comment: It's the very high pitched squealing sound. When it's stationary the car doesn't make the noise, only when it's reversing or quietly when going forwards.